# Failed "delete by query" query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I made a simply query

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://rtparamdev03:9200/_all/_query?pretty=true' -d '
{
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "missing" : { "field" : "path" }
        }
    }
   }
}'
```

I am getting a failure response.

```
{
"ok" : true,
"_indices" : {
"alerts" : {
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 5
  }
},
"logstash-2014.02.12" : {
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 5
  }
...
}
```

I don't see anything obvious in the ElasticSearch log. I see the following but I don't think that it's relevant at all.

I did an `all refresh` and I set `threadpool.index.queue_size=-1`. I'm still getting the same response.

Any advice please?

Comment: I think you are hitting [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5083). The reason why you don't get the actual failures back is [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5093), fixed now and will be part of the next release.

Comment: Hi @javanna Thanks for your reply. as per your links, I did a `all refresh` and I set `threadpool.index.queue_size=-1`. I'm still getting the same response, any further hint please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query string technique for Delete by query.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/<index>/<type>/_query?q=<attributeName>:<attributeValue>'
```

Reference

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/docs-delete-by-query.html